# Adding a new column in table once I've run an SQL select query

Tags: mysql

I've run the below SQL query in my phpMyAdmin interface to bring 3 columns together into one new column called `media_location` as below. Once I run the query I see the results exactly as expected but when I go back to my table I can't see the new column.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`rel_path`,`filename`,'.', `file_extension`) as media_location 
FROM `ulv8_jreviews_media`
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding the SELECT command. SELECT can be use only to consult data from your database. This command will never create a new column on the table.

Comment: You really don't need to have this new column on the table. From your application (i imagine you are developing one)you can run this query, a get the value you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement fetches data from the database. It does not change the underlying table structure. What you are doing is concatenating the values in the output of your SELECT query. These changes are not persisted in the database.

To change the table structure you need to execute `ALTER TABLE` statement and then populate the new column with some data.

```
ALTER TABLE ulv8_jreviews_media
    ADD media_location varchar(255);

UPDATE ulv8_jreviews_media SET media_location = CONCAT(`rel_path`,`filename`,'.', `file_extension`);
```